# GoLang: fatal error: too many callback functions

Tags: go

I am trying to write a go app that will monitor the status of a server application I run in windows. The application will run for roughly 16 hours before throwing out the following error: (Small snippet)

```
fatal error: too many callback functions

goroutine 137 [running]:
runtime.throw(0xc4c0a1, 0x1b)
        H:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:1117 +0x79 fp=0xc000639d30 sp=0xc000639d00 pc=0x899379
syscall.compileCallback(0xbd18a0, 0xc00041fce0, 0x1, 0x0)
        H:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:201 +0x5e5 fp=0xc000639e28 sp=0xc000639d30 pc=0x8c90e5
syscall.NewCallback(...)
        H:/Program Files/Go/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go:177
main.FindWindow(0xc47278, 0x13, 0xc000639f50, 0x2, 0x2)
```

I have two files. One is the file that is calling a bunch of Windows API stuff, and one is a goroutine that is being performed every 30 seconds to get an update.

I am fairly new to go, especially in windows related development, so I am struggling to find the issue and how to prevent it.

Here is the main file (test example).

```
func main() {
    go updateServerStats()

    select {}

}

func ServerStats() {

    serverStatsTicker := time.NewTicker(30 * time.Second)

    for range serverStatsTicker.C {

        serverRunning, serverHung, err := ServerHangCheck()
        if err != nil {
            ErrorLogger.Println("Server Check Error: ", err)
        }

        if serverHung {
            fmt.Println("Server is hung")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the primary callback/windows file. Its very much still a very rough, very work in progress. Something I found and modified from go playground.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    user32             = syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll")
    procEnumWindows    = user32.MustFindProc("EnumWindows")
    procGetWindowTextW = user32.MustFindProc("GetWindowTextW")
    procIsHungAppWindow = user32.MustFindProc("IsHungAppWindow")
)

//EnumWindows iterates over each window to be used for callbacks
func EnumWindows(enumFunc uintptr, lparam uintptr) (err error) {
    r1, _, e1 := syscall.Syscall(procEnumWindows.Addr(), 2, uintptr(enumFunc), uintptr(lparam), 0)
    if r1 == 0 {
        if e1 != 0 {
            err = error(e1)
        } else {
            err = syscall.EINVAL
        }
    }
    return
}

//GetWindowText gets the description of the Window, which is the "Text" of the window.
func GetWindowText(hwnd syscall.Handle, str *uint16, maxCount int32) (len int32, err error) {
    r0, _, e1 := syscall.Syscall(procGetWindowTextW.Addr(), 3, uintptr(hwnd), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(str)), uintptr(maxCount))
    len = int32(r0)
    if len == 0 {
        if e1 != 0 {
            err = error(e1)
        } else {
            err = syscall.EINVAL
        }
    }
    return
}

//IsHungAppWindow uses the IsHungAppWindow to see if Windows has been getting responses.
func IsHungAppWindow(hwnd syscall.Handle) (ishung bool, err error) {
    r2, _, err := syscall.Syscall(procIsHungAppWindow.Addr(), 2, uintptr(hwnd), 0, 0)
    if r2 == 1{
        return true, err
    } 
    return false, err
}

//FindWindow uses EnumWindows with a callback to GetWindowText, and if matches given Title, checks if its hung, and returns state.
func FindWindow(title string) (bool ,bool,  error) {
    var hwnd syscall.Handle
    var isHung bool = false
    cb := syscall.NewCallback(func(h syscall.Handle, p uintptr) uintptr {
        b := make([]uint16, 200)
        _, err := GetWindowText(h, &b[0], int32(len(b)))
        if err != nil {
            // ignore the error
            return 1 // continue enumeration
        }
        if syscall.UTF16ToString(b) == title {
            // note the window
            isHung, _ = IsHungAppWindow(h)

            hwnd = h

            return 0 // stop enumeration
        }
        return 1 // continue enumeration
    })

    EnumWindows(cb, 0)
    if hwnd == 0 {
        return false, false, fmt.Errorf("DCS Not Found")
    }
    
    if isHung == true {
        return true, isHung, fmt.Errorf("DCS Is Running But Hung")
    }

    return true, isHung, nil
}

//ServerHangCheck checks the server to see if the window is hung or process is running.
func ServerHangCheck() (bool, bool, error) {
    const title = "server_application"
    running, hung, err := FindWindow(title)

    return running, hung, err

}
```

Comment: You're creating a new anonymous function every time `FindWindow` is called.  This means you are creating a new callback every time.  Eventually you get to the point where you've created too many callbacks and crash the program (as suggested by your error message).  You'd need to find a way to re-use the same callback

Comment: Would I need to reuse it, or can I "close" the original?

Comment: I don't know if this will work but you could try https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/?GOOS=windows#CloseHandle  This function is undocumented, but it's my first guess.  It takes an argument of type `Handle`, which is has the underlying type of `uintptr` so you can convert with `syscall.Handle(cb)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the advice of torek I got a work around.

I created a global variable

```
var callbacker uintptr
```

Then then I created a function which is called by init

```
func init() {

    callbacker = syscall.NewCallback(CallBackCreator)

}


func CallBackCreator(h syscall.Handle, p uintptr) uintptr {
    hwnd = 0
    b := make([]uint16, 200)
    _, err := GetWindowText(h, &b[0], int32(len(b)))
    if err != nil {
        // ignore the error
        return 1 // continue enumeration
    }
    if syscall.UTF16ToString(b) == title {
        // note the window
        isHung, _ = IsHungAppWindow(h)

        hwnd = h

        return 0 // stop enumeration
    }
    return 1 // continue enumeration
}
```

which is now called by the function

```
EnumWindows(callbacker, 0)
```

Likely not the most "Go" appropriate way, but I am now making better progress.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`syscall.NewCallback`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go?s=5077:5117#L166), we find that it's actually implemented via `runtime/syscall_windows.go` as the function `compileCallback`:

```
func NewCallback(fn interface{}) uintptr {
        return compileCallback(fn, true)
}
```

Looking at the [runtime/syscall_windows.go](https://golang.org/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go) code we find that it has a fixed size table of all registered Go callbacks.  This code varies a lot between Go releases so it's not too productive to delve any further here.  However, there's one thing that is clear: the code checks to see if the callback function is *already registered*, and if so, *re-uses it*.  So a single callback function occupies one table slot, but adding multiple functions will eventually use up all the table slots and result in the `fatal error` that you encountered.

You asked in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66864829/golang-fatal-error-too-many-callback-functions#comment118195393_66864829) (the comments popped up while I was writing this):

> Would I need to reuse it, or can I "close" the original? – Mallachar 7 mins ago

You cannot close out the original.  There's an actual table of functions elsewhere in memory; a registered callback uses up a slot in this table, and slots are never released.

Comment: So, I am still confused as to how I would remediate this. Is there a way for me to maintain this callback? Or how would I remediate this? Sadly I am very new to both Go and Windows development (spent most time on Linux)

I thought about making the HWND a global variable, but if the server application closes and restarts, then I need to get the HWND again anyways.

Comment: You need to call `syscall.NewCallback` once, to establish some function (taking some set of arguments, and returning one uintptr as its result) as the callback. For instance: write `func windowCallBack(h syscall.Handle, p uintptr) uintptr { ... }` (fill in the code part), then make *one* call, one time, to create the callback handler. In the callback handler, use the `h` and `p` arguments as usual to do whatever you need to do. I'm not familiar with WIndows itself, though, so I have no idea how to code that properly.

Comment: My *guess* (but it's just a guess) is that the Windows callback here can pass a pointer through, so you could create a data structure that holds your two variables and supply that as the pointer argument. But without knowing more about how Windows works (or access to the right documentation) this guess isn't worth much.

Comment: Great, will try a few things out.

Comment: Alright I did like you suggested and it worked. I will add a new answer to my question